# COM+ Queued Components in .NET or something similar

Tags: c#, com+

I am trying to write an app which would wake up on-demand as the messages are queued in MSMQ, do some processing and go back to sleep. Now I am expecting only ~20 messages per day, so keeping a process alive 24/7 just to watch the queue may not be a good idea.

The [COM+ Queued Component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cwd2fx9t(v=vs.80).aspx) came to my mind and I am nostalgic now. I could create a dll and register it with RegSVC() and set it up under Component Services to be Queued. But there are a couple of problems with this.

1. I don't like the way ".NET Serviced Components" are deployed (RegSVC)
2. Microsoft is showing the following warning on their page about [Queued Components](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cwd2fx9t(v=vs.80).aspx)

> This document may not represent best practices for current
>   development, links to downloads and other resources may no longer be
>   valid. Current recommended version can be found here.
>   ArchiveDisclaimer

For those who don't know how Queued Components work (just a little summary)
You create an object of a component, and call a few methods. The methods weren't actually called, but a "Recorder" recorded what you did and placed them in an MSMQ Queue. Later on, when its your turn; the "Player" plays your method calls. Your component does not have to be awake 24/7 taking up CPU and Memory just to wait for messages.

Is there anything similar in .NET now?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can implement a queued component in .NET...

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/6b617zws(v=vs.80).aspx

If you're looking for a more modern approach, it's not .NET as such, but perhaps checkout...

http://gruntjs.com/

Comment: The .NET solution still requires me to go through the hassle of RegSVC right?